# What are the rules for Chrollo to steal an ability?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Chrollo, the leader of the Phantom Troupe possess a book which contains all of the abilities that he has stolen from other Nen Users. When he opens the book to a specific page where an ability is, he can use that ability.

We know that some conditions are needed to be complete before a certain ability can be activated.

My question is 'what are the rules that Chrollo needs to complete before he can steal the ability?'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Chrollo to steal a Nen ability from another Nen user four conditions must be met:

1. He must witness the Nen ability in action with his own eyes.
2. He must ask about the ability and be answered by the victim.
3. His victims palm must touch the handprint on the cover of Bandit's Secret.
4. All of the above must be completed within an hour.

Chrollo can only use a stolen ability when he has the Bandit's Secret open and on the page of the ability he wishes to use. The book must remain open and on that particular page for the full duration of the ability he choses, he can not close the book and still use the ability. Ref([Chrollo Lucilfer](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/Chrollo_Lucilfer))

Comment: Aren't you missing something? I thought it is five rule since the grandfather of Killua said this guess to Chrollo and in Chrollos mind it seems that guess was correct.

Comment: @OdracirPapa During the fight Zeno Zoldyck states: "He'll have to meet four or maybe five conditions before he can accomplish it." This means that Zeno was guessing on how many conditions needed to be met. He did not know for sure he was just using his knowledge to give a good estimation on how Chrollo's ability worked.